# Multithreading monitor process parallel-processing in php

Tags: php, parallel-processing

I found this example on the php site I would like to run a command and monitor the process which its running. 
please find below the class code.

```
class Process{
private $pid;
private $command;

public function __construct($cl=false){
    if ($cl != false){
        $this->command = $cl;
        $this->runCom();
    }
}
private function runCom(){
    $command = 'nohup '.$this->command.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
    exec($command ,$op);
    $this->pid = (int)$op[0];
}

public function setPid($pid){
    $this->pid = $pid;
}

public function getPid(){
    return $this->pid;
}

public function status(){
    $command = 'ps -p '.$this->pid;
    exec($command,$op);
    if (!isset($op[1]))return false;
    else return true;
}

public function start(){
    if ($this->command != '')$this->runCom();
    else return true;
}

public function stop(){
    $command = 'kill '.$this->pid;
    exec($command);
    if ($this->status() == false)return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Below is the script I used to run it.

```
require 'class.php';
$process = new Process('ls -al');
    // Then you can start/stop/ check status of the job.
    $process.stop();
    $process.start();
    if ($process.status()){
        echo "The process is currently running";
    }else{
        echo "The process is not running.";
    }
```

I get an error saying undefined function start()

Comment: I get an error saying undefined function start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$process->start();
```

that's the correct php syntax.

Comment: I used it and I it throws the process is not running. but in the command line i put in ls -al it works.

Comment: `ls -al` might not be a good test scenario, because it only runs for some milliseconds. Try something that takes more time.

Comment: Could you kindly suggest a command I could try am new to linux commands

Comment: copy a file, do `du -hs /usr` ... be creative